# Stop html form submission

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, forms, http-post

Hi I have HTML form which I have an onclick event where it prompts the user e.g. if sure yes/no. If no is selected its suppose to stop the form from submitting but it seems to process through as the dialog is being called async. I'm using a jquery plugin http://marcosesperon.es/apps/messi/ for displaying my prompt.

Below is a snippet of my code:

```
    <div id="buttonCommnads">
        <button type="submit" class="k-button cancel" id="save" value="Save" title="Save inspection so it may be submitted at a later time" onclick="processCommand(COMMAND.SAVE);">Save</button>
        <button type="submit" class="k-button" id="Submit" value="Submit" title="Submit inspection" onclick="return processCommand(COMMAND.SUBMIT);">Submit</button>
        @*<button type="submit" class="k-button" id="email" title="Generate draft email for inspection photos" onclick="processCommand(COMMAND.EMAIL);">Email</button>*@
        <button type="button" class="k-button" id="cancel" title="Discard changes" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Index", "Inspections")'">Cancel</button>
    </div>
```

and then the javascript function:

```
<script>

var COMMAND = {
    SAVE: { value: 0, name: "Save", tense: "saved" },
    EMAIL: { value: 1, name: "Email", tense: "emailed" },
    SUBMIT: { value: 2, name: "Submit", tense: "submitted" },
};

function processCommand(command) {
    if (command == COMMAND.EMAIL) {

    }
    else if (command == COMMAND.SAVE) {
        $('#Submit').val(command.name);
        $('#inspectionForm').submit();
    }
    else if (command == COMMAND.SUBMIT) {
        $('#Submit').val(command.name);
        var photosAttached = '@Model.Survey.SitePhotoes.Count()';
        console.log('processCommand: submit - begin');
        if (photosAttached >= 1) {
            console.log('processCommand: submit photos attached.');
            return true;
        } else {
            console.log('processCommand: prompt messi.');
            new Messi('Are you sure you wish to submit as no inspections photos are currently attached?', {
                title: command.name + ' Inspection',
                buttons: [{ id: 0, label: 'Yes', val: 'Y', btnClass: 'btn-success' },
                            { id: 1, label: 'No', val: 'N', btnClass: 'btn-danger' }],
                modal: true,
                callback: function (val) {
                    if (val == 'Y') {
                        console.log('processCommand: yes.');
                        return true;
                    }
                    else {
                        console.log('processCommand: no.');
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        console.log('processCommand: submit - end');
    }
```

}

I'm using ASP.NET MVC 4 and I'm fairly new to web development so please excuse my ignorance. Any help greatly appreciated.

Vince.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dialog is acting asynchronously and there is no way to prevent this. But what you can do is ensure the form is not submitted on clicking the button and instead submit it from within the callback if appropriate:

Html:

```
<button type="submit" class="k-button" id="email" title="Generate draft email for inspection photos" onclick="(function() {processCommand(COMMAND.EMAIL);return false;})()">Email</button>
```

Javascript:

```
function processCommand(command) {
    if (command == COMMAND.EMAIL) {

    }
    else if (command == COMMAND.SAVE) {
        $('#Submit').val(command.name);
        $('#inspectionForm').submit();
    }
    else if (command == COMMAND.SUBMIT) {
        $('#Submit').val(command.name);
        var photosAttached = '@Model.Survey.SitePhotoes.Count()';
        console.log('processCommand: submit - begin');
        if (photosAttached >= 1) {
            console.log('processCommand: submit photos attached.');
            return true;
        } else {
            console.log('processCommand: prompt messi.');
            new Messi('Are you sure you wish to submit as no inspections photos are currently attached?', {
                title: command.name + ' Inspection',
                buttons: [{ id: 0, label: 'Yes', val: 'Y', btnClass: 'btn-success' },
                            { id: 1, label: 'No', val: 'N', btnClass: 'btn-danger' }],
                modal: true,
                callback: function (val) {
                    if (val == 'Y') {
                        console.log('processCommand: yes.');
                        $("form:first").submit();
                    }
                    else {
                        console.log('processCommand: no.');
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        console.log('processCommand: submit - end');
    }
```

Comment: thank you for the reply, I put in your changes and now I'm getting the following error: function statement requires a name. Do you know what the issue is?

Comment: Sorry I was missing some brackets in the html line. Please try it now

Comment: thanks for the help appreciate it. I also had to add event.preventDefault();

Answer (score 0):

You stop form submission by preventing default action of `submit` event. `click` event isn't quite appropriate, as the form can be submitted using the keyboard as well.

In jQuery it's:

```
$('form').on('submit', function(){
    return false;
})
```

Since your prompt is asynchronous you'll always have to stop normal submission and force submit with `form.submit()` when user presses "Yes".

Comment: Thank for the response, so in my case I would have two functions? one is your function e.g.  $('form').on('submit', function(){
    return false;
}) and then in my original function I would put form.submit if the user answered yes?

Comment: Why would you let the button be a submit button if you always block the default action and trigger it by jQuery when needed? Change it to a normal button (not a submit button) as I suggested in my answer, then you don't have to block anything.

Comment: Thanks appreciate the response. I'm fairly new so didn't really know too much of javascript just learning as I go.

Comment: @Iljaas @vinceanon if you use regular button, then only clicks on that button (mouse, explicit keyboard tabbing) will activate the prompt, but submission of the form with the Enter key (or any other mechanism like password manager) **will bypass the handler**. So the only reliable way is to use `onsubmit` and submit buttons everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

```
event.preventDefault();
```

Use it to prevent the default behaviour.

[More info](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_preventdefault.asp)

Comment: Thank for the response, in my current code I don't have event being passed to my function. Do I just put that in the start of my function and then submit my form when the user clicks yes?

Answer (score 0):

I would change the submit buttons to normal buttons (change `type="submit"` to `type="button"`). And then, in the function that is triggered by the button, if you evaluate that the user has pressed "yes", submit the form using jQuery:

`('#yourFormID').submit();`

Otherwise just `return false`.

Edit: I noticed that you're already triggering the `submit()` using jQuery, so the button doesn't need to be of the `submit` type. What happens if you just change the button `type` to `button` instead of `submit` and add a `return false` in case you don't want to submit anything? Doesn't that do what you meant in your question?

Comment: Yep, your right this would correct it. I'm fairly new to javascript etc so kinda learn as I go. Thanks for the help the information provided by everyone has been really helpful  to try to understand what is going on and how things flow.